# How to record or download stream buffer from shoutcast url in external directory android

Tags: android, url, buffer, recording, shoutcast

I am playing shoutcast url with the help of Exoplayer , i want to save the buffer  as .mp3  file format .. i am using this code but this is saving stream very very slow as i am recording stream for 5 min it is only recording stream of about 15-20 sec .. please help me ... thanks in advance for your contribution...

```
      outputSource.append( "//samplefile.mp3" );
    String os;
   os = outputSource.toString();
   fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( os );
 inputStream = new URL( "http://my_url" ).openStream();
while    (true) 
{
int c;
while((c=inputStream.read())!= -1)
{
Log.d(LOG_TAG,"bytesRead="+bytesRead);
fileOutputStream.write(c);
bytesRead++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i am recording stream for 5 min it is only recording stream of about 15-20 sec` that is because you are reading it byte by byte.
You need to use a buffer:

```
int l;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((l = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
}
```

---

Also your `while(true)` cycle is useless